# tkinterのダイアログファイルのパスを引数として扱う

Tags: python, python3, numpy, tkinter

現在tkinterを用いてダイアログを開いています。
ファイルのパスは取得したのですが、このファイルをf1,f2に代入したいです。
どうすればよいでしょうか？

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('微笑山') #タイトル
root.geometry('400x200') #サイズ 横x縦

#selctボタンを押したときの処理
def select_click():
    messagebox.showinfo('select','真のデータ')
    messagebox.showinfo('select','測定データ')
    fileType = [('Excelファイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプをExcelファイルに指定
    fileType = [('Excelファイル','*.txt')] #ファイルタイプをExcelファイルに指定
    iniDir1 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
    iniDir2 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) #初期表示フォルダ
    filepath1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir1)
    filepath2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileType,initialdir = iniDir2)
    messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath1)
    messagebox.showinfo('選択したファイル',filepath2)

#ボタンを作成
selectButton = tkinter.Button(root, text='fast Select',command=select_click)
selectButton.pack()

root.mainloop()



x1_list=[] # data1格納用のx_listを定義
z1_list=[] # data1格納用のz_listを定義
x2_list=[] # data2格納用のx_listを定義
z2_list=[] # data2格納用のz_listを定義

f1=open('root') 
f2=open('filepath2') # プロットしたいデータが入っているファイルをr(読み込み) t(テキスト)モードで読み込む

#data1読み込み
for line in f1:
    data1 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x1_list.append(float(data1[0]))
    z1_list.append(float(data1[1]))
#data２読み込み
for line in f2:
    data2 = line[:-1].split(' ')
    x2_list.append(float(data2[0]))
    z2_list.append(float(data2[1]))
##
plt.xlabel('X') # ｘ軸のラベル
plt.ylabel('Z') # y軸のラベル

plt.plot(x1_list, z1_list, color="White", alpha=0.8, linewidth=4.0, label="data1")
plt.plot(x2_list, z2_list, color="White", alpha=0.8, linewidth=4.0, label="data2")
plt.legend()
plt.fill_between(np.append(x1_list, x2_list[::-1]), np.append(z1_list, z2_list[::-1]),where=z2_list>=z1_list, facecolor='green', interpolate=True)#二線の間の色を表す
plt.fill_between(np.append(x1_list, x2_list[::-1]), np.append(z1_list, z2_list[::-1]),where=z2_list<=z1_list,facecolor='red', interpolate=True)#二線の間の色を表す


# その他，描画用オプション
plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(fontsize=10) 
plt.ylim([-21.62, -21.46])
plt.grid(True) #グラフの枠を作成
plt.savefig("cm.png")
plt.show()
fig = plt.figure()
```

Comment: `filepath1`, `filepath2` をグローバルな変数として定義し、それに代入するのが簡単でしょう。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/221928

Comment: その存在を知りませんでした

Answer (score -2):

グローバル変数でやってみます
kunifさんご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: せっかくなので、(コメントを受けて)実際にご自身で **試した結果** を回答として投稿してもらうと、他のユーザーにとっても助けとなる情報になるかと思います。 / 今のままだと単なるコメントに近い内容なので、コミュニティによって "質が低い回答" とみなされてしまう可能性があります。